# AS3 package issue

Tags: actionscript-3, package

Really want to refactor and re-architect my project, it's become basically an 11k line monobloc that desperately needs to be split into multiple classes (and class files) inside a single package.

Yes I know I should have figured all this out when I started, but this is play not work and I was brand new to AS3 when I started. And I've kept building and building and it all works, it's just become very hard to manage.

My immediate goal is to define a package and then start breaking out function groups from the current main class into subclasses that extend the base. But I'm having a problem with the first step - defining the package.

I'm getting:

C:\Users\Vossie\Documents\Fex Line of Battle Project\trunk\line_of_battle\LOB_Core.as, Line 1, Column 1 5001: The name of package 'line_of_battle' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. C:\Users\Vossie\Documents\Fex Line of Battle Project\trunk\line_of_battle\LOB_Core.as

So I've checked:

```
package line_of_battle {
public class LOB_Core extends flash.display.MovieClip {
```

Filename is LOB_Core.as.

Path:
[image: Physical path on machine]

I explicitly added it to the class search path:

[image: Class path]

So:

**Name of package agrees with name of folder (I actually pasted it from folder to .as file)**

**Package file is within that folder.**

**Class search path includes that folder**

**Shouldn't matter for this but filename and public class name match**

**I've searched stack overflow** and one similar case involved a text case mismatch that I don't see here. One other related question the guy's question turned into just how to make classes and name the files correctly.

According to the documentation I read, this should work fine. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

**Edit - This is the code that's triggering the error, LOB_Core.as:1102** -

```
var test:LOB_Scenario_Data = new LOB_Scenario_Data();
```

And the class that is calling:

```
package line_of_battle {

import line_of_battle.LOB_Core.*;

public class LOB_Scenario_Data extends LOB_Core {

    public function LOB_Scenario_Data() {
        // constructor code

        trace("BIG MONKEYS");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It may just be that you've added `C:\Users\Vossie\Documents\Fex Line of Battle Project\trunk\line_of_battle` as a source path. Does it work if you remove that? The reason is that your source path should be the root and folders *within that* are packages. You may have confused the compiler into looking for a folder within `line_of_battle` called `line_of_battle`. If you were to have an empty package statement (`package` followed by nothing), that would be valid as a file in the root of one of the source paths.

Comment: You can have a look at [an ActionScript 3 project of mine](https://github.com/MartyWallace/Sentinel) for more information. Here, I have `src` as a source path and within that the `sentinel` package.

Comment: Removed both of the custom paths I added and sadly no luck. One other piece of possibly-relevant info is that the line_of_battle folder was copied from another folder and renamed, as were all the files and classes inside. After copying and SVN adding and doing all the renaming, the name of the package error is what I'm getting

Comment: You should keep the second one ending in `trunk` and just remove the one before that.

Comment: Re-added that path, still no luck. This is perverse. I looked at your Sentinel framework, very cool. For the purposes of this question I'm seeing the same layout/naming I'm using. It may also be something I want to use in the future, but for now have enjoyed building pretty much everything I need from scratch.

Comment: No other suggestions from anyone? This remains unsolved. I even built a couple new test files in a totally different directory with all new names for everything, a package and a child class, and I get the exact same error where it insists the package name does not agree with the directory name, even though that is clearly not the case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to abandon this thread. It's interesting that you're having the same problem with completely fresh projects.

Comment: Try putting [something like this](https://gist.github.com/MartyWallace/61b6006a1cb0621a970fdddde9d08fb7) into a directory called `src`, then add `C:\Wherever\On\Your\PC\src` as a source path and see if `new Test` gets you anything in the document class of a fresh project.

Comment: Thanks Marty, will give that a try this evening.